# How do you check if number is divisible by 2 in txt file?

Tags: c

I'm trying to find numbers from txt file divisible by 2. And if they are not divisible by 2, print for example ("Try different number.")
For example (input looks like this){
4242
1620
33
1486
}

```
int main(){
    FILE* file;
    int i = 0;
    char load [100];
    file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(load, sizeof load, file) != NULL){
        if (i == 0){
            printf("Numbers divisible by 2: %s", load);
        }
        i++;
        if (i == 1){i = 0;}
    }
}
```

This is as far as I can go. I tried  I'm like few days new in C, I'm sorry.

Comment: There's nothing in the posted code that actually looks at the contents of the line after its been read into `load`.  Also, 10 characters seems painfully small for a buffer.  Why so small?  You should expect to read incomplete lines with such a small buffer.

Comment: A number is even if the last digit in its decimal representation is even.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if `fopen` succeeded.
2. Discard any line feed or space characters from the `fgets` input if you have reason to believe any are present.
3. Convert the string to an integer using `strtol`.
4. Check if the integer is divisible by 2 with the modulus operator: `if(n%2 == 0)`, where `n%2` gives the reminder of `n/2` expressed as a fixed point integer.
5. Use `fclose`.

Comment: When using `strtol`, step 2 is not necessary, as the function skips leading whitespace and ignores trailing whitspace.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Oh yeah that's true... Well anyway, it's good practice for beginners (and everyone else) to sanitize the input first of all.

Comment: @Lundin it is giving me a wrong values, it changes to something different.

Comment: @sccc444 So post your attempts as a separate question, I can't read your mind.